# Image upload to AWS S3 fails instantly from a different region but succeeds if in the same region as the bucket

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am uploading an image directly to AWS bucket which works perfectly fine from my location (India). The same code fails to upload an image when the user location is Singapore.

Following is the method I'm using to upload the image.

```
func uploadMediaOnS3(contentType: String = "application/octet-stream", mediaData: Data, folderName: String, fileName: String, progressBlock:@escaping (_ uploadProgress: Float, _ uploadStatus: Bool) -> Void) {

    //Configure Credentials
    let credentialProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: "my-access-key", secretKey: "my-secret-key")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: .APSouth1, credentialsProvider: credentialProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 90.0
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 90.0
    //Setup Progress Block
    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(" ==> \(Float(progress.fractionCompleted * 100))")
            progressBlock(Float(progress.fractionCompleted * 100), false)
        }
    }

    //Setup Completion Block
    let uploadCompletionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if error != nil {
                progressBlock(-1.0, false)
            } else {
                progressBlock(100.0, true)
            }
        }
    }

    //Upload Data
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    transferUtility.uploadData(mediaData, bucket: "my-bucket-name", key: "\(folderName)\(fileName)", contentType: contentType, expression: expression, completionHandler: uploadCompletionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
        if task.error != nil {
            progressBlock(-1.0, false)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Following are my AWS SDK details :

AWSCore (version : 2.6.13)

AWSS3 (version : 2.6.13)

My guess would be that there is some issue with the region. I found out that my bucket location falls under .APSouth1 (Mumbai, India) and works fine here but when being used from Singapore, it fails due to the fact that it is falling under .APSoutheast1

One more thing to note, may be important, is that the upload fails instantly, as soon as it starts. There is no issue of timeout or anything.

It is also possible that I might be missing some settings here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
func sendMultiPartAWS(path: String, imgData: Data, onComplete: @escaping (JSON, NSError?, URLResponse?) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError?, URLResponse?) -> Void) {

        Alamofire.upload(imgData, to: path, method: .put).responseJSON { response in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {

                let swiftyJSON = JSON.init(response.data!)
                onComplete(swiftyJSON, nil, response.response)

             } else {
            }
         }
    }
```

I have used above code to upload image in AWS, may this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Bucket name is global, but location is not. The following is quoted from [Bucket Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html):

> Objects belonging to a bucket that you create in a specific AWS Region never leave that region, unless you explicitly transfer them to another region. For example, objects stored in the EU (Ireland) region never leave it.

You can use [cross-region replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) facility to have the same content across the regions

Comment: Isn't your solution regarding accessing the content already uploaded ?
The problem is that the upload is failing from a different region. and that is with the error AWSTranferUtilityErrorDomain(code=2).
P.S. It is only failing from Singapore, and successful from India or SouthAfrica. (atleast I've had success results from these places.)